# Does html font size not work in informative text in QMessageBox?

Tags: html, c++, qt, qt5, qmessagebox

The Informative Text of a `QMessageBox` can be formatted as rich text, and I understood that the html **<font></font>** tag was allowable for rich text in this context. However, the **size** attribute does not seem to work as expected. When used, the size of the `QMessageBox` informative text is larger than normal, but the specific value seemingly has no effect (even though the attribute **color**, and the **<i>** & **<b>** tags seem to work as expected). Here's the output:

[image: <code>QMessageBox</code> seems insensitive to font tag's size attribute]

Is there a way to specify font sizes in html (or rtf) markup in the Informative Text of a `QMessageBox`?

```
void MainWindow::about()
{
    QMessageBox msgAbout;
    msgAbout.setInformativeText("<span style='text-align: center'><p><b><font size = 20 color = red><i>Supposedly</i> set in 30pt font</font><p><font size = 20 color = blue><i>Rumoredly</i> set in 20pt font</font><p><font size = 10 color = green><i>Putatively</i> set in 10pt font</font><p>Proud not to use the &lt;font&gt; tag!</span><p>");
    msgAbout.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
    msgAbout.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Ok);
    msgAbout.exec();
}
```

macOS 10.13.3
Qt Creator 4.5 based on Qt 5.10.0 (Clang 7.0 (Apple), 64 bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `:` instead of `=`:. You have to place `font-size` within the style attribute of the relevant `<p>` tag. And you have to specify the font size units (e.g., `12pt`).

```
QMessageBox msgAbout;
msgAbout.setInformativeText("<span style='text-align: center'><p style='font-size: 30pt; color: red'><b><i>Supposedly</i> set in 30pt font</p><p style='font-size: 20pt; color: blue'><i>Rumoredly</i> set in 20pt font</p><p style='font-size: 10pt; color: green'><i>Putatively</i> set in 10pt font</p><p>Proud not to specify font-size attributes!</span><p>");
msgAbout.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
msgAbout.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Ok);
msgAbout.exec();
```

[image]

Comment: @Alexis I think that the size of the image does not help in visualizing the difference in size between the fonts